# JAXB Marshaller | ValidationEventHandler how to get whole complex object in locator

Tags: xsd, jaxb, marshalling, xsd-validation

I am using JAXB javax.xml.bind.Marshaller to marshal XML and also doing XSD validation as a part of it.

My object to be marshal is of complex type like below
I have complex class like below

```
 class A{
    private B b;
    private C c;
    }
```

where B and C are other classes.

In case of XSD validation failure, I am getting proper error message in configured javax.xml.bind.ValidationEventHandler.

but the problem is, I am getting ***locator.object*** only either B or C where XSD validation fails.

[severity=FATAL_ERROR,message=cvc-maxLength-valid: Value 'test' with length = '4' is not facet-valid with respect to maxLength '1' for type '#AnonType_xxxxx'.,locator=[url=null,line=-1,column=-1,node=null,**object=com.....C@1f4304be**,field=null]]

Here, Is there any way that along with above message I can get always a full class object i.e. **object=com.....A@1f4304be** so that I can cast it and use for my futher business processing.

The challenge is Class B is the only class which contains unique identifier of users and hence whenever there is a failure for class C only, I am not able to find for which user, this failed as Class C does not have any unique information about user.

Seeking for advice and solution!